# What does version after "?" mean in src or href attribute and whats its function? "front1c9b.js?ver=4.6.1"

Tags: html, css

what does the ?ver=4.6.1 mean in the src attribute of the script tag?
what is its function?

I have also seen the similar in style tags such as "?feed"

Comment: Those are simply "parameters", here called "GET arguments". Please read a basic introduction about how the web and http requests work. It will answer many questions you have.

Answer (score 1):

It is just to force a fresh download of the script file in case the browser cached it. Browser cached the script with its file name, adding ?ver=xxx will still link to the same address, but browser sees it as a different file name and so will download a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

thats just a url parameter. Some webservers will interpet this and return different javascript files, other times arbritrary values get passed in to help evade caching mechanisms (as urls are typically the key for whether or not this resource should be served up from cached resource)